# debugging android application on sony xperia device

Tags: android

What is the procedure to debug the android eclipse in sony experia

Answer (score 0):

The Google USB driver is a downloadable component for Windows developers, available for download from the AVD and SDK Manager.

This question is answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827958/how-to-connect-sony-xperia-mini-pro-for-android-debugging)