# Debugging android application on devices +With Sony Ericsson

Tags: android, usb, emulation

Here i saw various question related to **"usb debugging"** but answers not really helped me . can any one put light on this issue...
`Your any help is appreciable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**My problem solved after doing this**

I updated usb driver :
[image]

i followed step written **[here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)** under WINDOWS XP .

Device manager view

[image]

and ...

1. i reconnected my device to pc(winXP).
2. enabled usb debugging in device
3. usb debugging= set true in android manifest
4. In command prompt...

   ```
   C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb devices 
   List of devices attached 
   emulator-5554   device
   e4567855....    device
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For most android phones you will also need to install custom adb drivers in order to get it to work. Try installing any software suites that came with the phone as these may have the required drivers. Otherwise look on google for the adb drivers for the particular phone.
For the xperia in particular I was unable to get adb to find the phone until it was upgraded to 2.1 so you may need to do this if you are using an older android version.

Comment: i updated to 2.1. how to install custom adb drivers ? i went through "developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/downloads/download/…; this site and downloaded it and copied to /androidSDK/google-usbdriver folder...

Comment: I don't know where the drivers are at the moment. The company websites tend to be a mess when you are trying to find something. Usually I get there from a forum link somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you run *android* at a command prompt it brings up the Android SDK Manager: under "**Available Packages** expand the **Third party Add-Ons** option. There looks to be a new Sony-Ericsson driver. Making sure you have that downloaded and then update the driver for your device from the downloaded driver file may solve your problem.