# connecting my android phone to laptop

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm developing an android app using Eclipse. My laptop's WiFi just died on me and I've just bought myself a new laptop. The problem is that the new laptop is not seeing my Samsung nexux S when I hook it up via USB. I have all the app's Manifest file set to Debuggable and the phone settings are set properly. Does anyone what the problem is?

PS Both laptops are HP

Comment: Make sure the Nexus drivers are installed.

Comment: you can find the driver you need if you search for something like: Nexus S adb driver

Answer (score 0):

You need to check

```
  Nexus s Driver is installed .
```

> Google has release the USB Driver for Windows, revision 4, which include the support for recent launched “Google Samsung NEXUS S”

See a very good link  [here](http://samsung-phones-apps.com/samsung-nexus-s-usb-driver-for-windows.html)

- Then double check  Usb debugging enabled on your phone

Its done!

You can refer this   [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827958/how-to-connect-sony-xperia-mini-pro-for-android-debugging) too

Answer (score 0):

Go to    http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html[image]